# Jabbler instant messaging implementation with mysql for a LAN?

Tags: server, mysql, jabber

how to how do I configure a Jabber IM server on Ubuntu and how do I test with users on LAN?

Comment: Do you mean setting up a Jabber server ?

Comment: what does the mysql part have to do with your question?

Answer (score 1):

OpenFire is a free XMPP server that can use MySQL or LDAP for users, rosters, etc. It's been a while since I've used it, but it used to be very easy to configure. Everything is just point and click and a matter of choosing names and passwords, mostly.

You can find out more about it here: http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/

There are also other XMPP servers in the archives, but I don't have any personal experience with them. I would recommend that you try OpenFire first since it's probably the easiest one. It does not necessarily mean it's the best solution for long term use. I'm not qualified to be the judge of that, so I would recommend that you have a look at other servers as well.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on sun java which is not supported by ubuntu now, so here is simple tutorial with pictures how to install Openfire and java to work on 12.04: http://linuxibos.blogspot.com/2012/05/setup-openfire-communicator-on-ubuntu.html